# msi is complaining that it is unable to run DLL error 1723(1157)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am creating a sample msi. I am using a C++ custom action. I am able to install the msi on Windows 7 32bit. But I am unable to install it on Windows Server 2008 64bit.

The following is the code:

```
 <Binary Id="BinaryId.dll"
       SourceFile="Test.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="TestFunc" BinaryKey="BinaryId" DllEntry="TestFunc"
              Execute="immediate" Return="check"  />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="TestFunc" Before="InstallInitialize" Overridable="yes">1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I am getting the following error from the msi logs:

> ```
>  Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI84EB.tmp, Entrypoint: MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:17:180]: Doing action: TestFunc
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:17:180]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
> Action start 1:28:17: TestFunc.
> MSI (s) (8C:A0) [01:28:17:184]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8E90.tmp, Entrypoint: TestFunc
> CustomAction TestFunc returned actual error code 1157 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:17:218]: Note: 1: 1723 2: TestFunc3: TestFunc4: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8E90.tmp 
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:17:218]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:17:218]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1723 
> MSI (c) (1C:74) [01:28:17:224]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg
>
>
> Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action TestFunc, entry: TestFunc, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8E90.tmp 
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:18:451]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:18:451]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
> MSI (s) (8C:30) [01:28:18:451]: Product: TestCa -- Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action TestFunc, entry: TestFunc, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8E90.tmp
> ```

Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions and help that would lead to resolve this issue. :)

Comment: Can you show us the TestFunc method ? It might be related to what you are doing in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what you are using the custom action method TestFunc. 1157 error means that:

> One of the library files needed to run this application cannot be
>   found.

So you might be using some library that is not available on Windows Server 2008 64bit but it is available on Windows 7 32bit.

Comment: thank you. it was helpful. :) turned out that one of the dependent library was missing

Answer (score 0):

Writing custom actions in managed .Net code is not easy and involves manually manipulating the project files.  If you can easily write the same code in VB Script, JavaScript or C++, I'd recommend taking that path instead.

Here's the tutorial I used: [Creating Custom Action for WIX Written in Managed Code without Votive](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/wixcustomaction.aspx).